# Как сравнить массивы PHP правильно?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть много массивов типа:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 12512650 
[1] => https://www.makfsa.ru/ 
[2] => https://ru.wikipsedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%84%D0%B0 
[3] => http://makfa.nichosst.ru/ 
[4] => http://ru.makfapasta.com/production/product/pasta/ 
[5] => http://ru.makfapasta.com/ 
[6] => https://www.utkaonos.ru/item/42/1096519 
[7] => https://www.utkonos.ru/item/42/1096522 
[8] => https://www.utkonos.ru/item/1381/3223485 
[9] => https://www.uatkonos.ru/item/42/1096527 
[10] => https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/ 
)
```

Таких массивов может быть от 2х до 20и.

Есть так же массив типа:

```
Array ( 
[obj] => 
   Array ( 
   [0] => 
      Array ( 
       [url] => https://www.utkonos.ru/item/1381/3223485 
       [ton] => Не определена 
       [type] => Не определен 
       ) 
   [1] => 
      Array ( 
       [url] => https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/ 
       [ton] => Не определена 
       [type] => Не определен 
      ) 
   [2] => Array ( 
       [url] => http://makfa.nichost.ru/ 
       [ton] => Не определена 
       [type] => Не определен 
      ) 
   [3] => Array ( 
       [url] => https://ru.wikipedia.org/wikif/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%84%D0%B0 
       [ton] => Не определена 
       [type] => Не определен 
      ) 
   [4] => Array ( 
       [url] => http://ru.makfapasta.com/producftion/product/pasta/
       [ton] => Не определена
       [type] => Не определен ) 
   [5] => Array ( 
       [url] => http://ru.mafkfapasta.com/ 
       [ton] => Не определена 
       [type] => Не определен 
    ) ....
```

Необходимо `url` из второго массива сравнить с с первыми массивами и образовать новые массива типа первых, но уже с добавлением соответствующих `ton` и `type` значений. Как?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
<?php
$first_array = array( '......' );
$last_array = array( '......' );
$result = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $first_array ); $i++ ) {
    $key = array_search( $first_array[ $i ], $last_array, true );
    if ( $key ) {
        $result[ $i ][ 'url' ] = $last_array[ $key ][ 'url' ];
        $result[ $i ][ 'url' ] = $last_array[ $key ][ 'ton' ];
        $result[ $i ][ 'url' ] = $last_array[ $key ][ 'type' ];
    }
}

print_r( $result );


?>
```

p.s  Не забудьте подменить ваши массивы на мои ($first_array,$last_array)

Answer (score 1):

Ваши массивы:

```
$arr_1 = [
    '12512650',
    'https://www.makfsa.ru/',
    'https://ru.wikipsedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%84%D0%B0',
    'http://makfa.nichosst.ru/',
    'http://ru.makfapasta.com/production/product/pasta/',
    'http://ru.makfapasta.com/',
    'https://www.utkaonos.ru/item/42/1096519',
    'https://www.utkonos.ru/item/42/1096522',
    'https://www.utkonos.ru/item/1381/3223485',
    'https://www.uatkonos.ru/item/42/1096527',
    'https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/'
];

$arr_2 = [
    'obj' =>  [
        [
           'url' => 'https://www.utkonos.ru/item/1381/3223485',
           'ton' => 'Не определена',
           'type' => 'Не определен'
        ],
        [
           'url' => 'https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/',
           'ton' => 'Не определена',
           'type' => 'Не определен'
        ],
        [
           'url' => 'http://makfa.nichost.ru/',
           'ton' => 'Не определена',
           'type' => 'Не определен'
        ],
        [
           'url' => 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wikif/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%84%D0%B0',
           'ton' => 'Не определена',
           'type' => 'Не определен'
        ],
        [
           'url' => 'http://ru.makfapasta.com/producftion/product/pasta/',
           'ton' => 'Не определена',
           'type' => 'Не определен'
        ],
        [
           'url' => 'http://ru.mafkfapasta.com/',
           'ton' => 'Не определена',
           'type' => 'Не определен'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Тогда решение можно записать так:

```
$new = [];

foreach($arr_2 as $key => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $a) {
        $url = array_intersect(array_column($arr_2[$key], 'url'), $arr_1);
        ! in_array($a['url'], $url) ?: $new[] = $a;
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

В результате работы скрипта будет получен массив:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string 'https://www.utkonos.ru/item/1381/3223485' (length=40)
      'ton' => string 'Не определена' (length=25)
      'type' => string 'Не определен' (length=23)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string 'https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/' (length=41)
      'ton' => string 'Не определена' (length=25)
      'type' => string 'Не определен' (length=23)
```