# Собрать массив php из двух массивов?

Tags: php, массивы

Первый массив:

```
 Array
 ( [0] => Array 
( [0] => Array ( [0] => https://www.makfsa.ru/ [1] => 12512650 [2] => google ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => https://ru.wikipsedia.org/wiki/%D0%9 [1] => 12512650 [2] => google ) .......
```

Второй массив:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/ [ton] => Не определена [type] => Не определен ) 
[1] => Array ( [url] => http://ru.makfapasta.com/producftion/product/pasta/ [ton] => Не определена [type] => Не определен )...
```

Как собрать массив типа

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://proactions.ru/actions/food/makfa/ [ton] => Не определена [type] => Не определен [id] => 12512650 [s] => google) 
[1] => Array ( [url] => http://ru.makfapasta.com/producftion/product/pasta/ [ton] => Не определена [type] => Не определен [id] => 12512650 [s] => google) ....
```

то есть чтоб к УРЛу добавлялись дополнительные значения из двух массивов.
Спасибо!

Comment: я же вам скидывал решение в одной из предыдущих тем - вы видели?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнить массивы PHP правильно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808889/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-php-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Эдуард, вопрос похожий, но есть отличия. Вам вообще отдельное спасибо за помощь!!! Извините меня если я  не отвечаю на ваши ответы. Просто мне тяжело все дается и нужно много времени чтоб все понять.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то `url` надо взять из первого массива и взять остальные ключи. Используйте `array_map`

```
 $result = array_map(function($a,$b){
                    return [
                        'url' => $a[0],
                        'id'  => $a[1], 
                        'ton' => $b['ton'],
                        .....
                    ];
               }, $arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: да, но тут как бы необходимо сравнить УРЛы и им присвоить им соответствующие значения.

Comment: @youruncle как бы возьмите и вопрос напишите корректно тогда, чтоб было написано что и как вы хотите сравнить, ибо в том виде в котором он сейчас ничего не ясно.

Comment: **извините**!!!!